# Pass Uint8List to Pointer<Void> in dart:ffi

Tags: dart

I have a C function with the Following signature

```
bool sendFrame(int width, int height, int channelNumber, void *data, bool clone);
```

data here being a raw image.

My ffi function signature is:

```dart
  final int Function(int, int, int, Pointer<Void>, int) rPPGSendFrame = rPPGLib
      .lookup<
          NativeFunction<
              Int32 Function(
                  Int32, Int32, Int32, Pointer<Void>, Int32)>>("sendFrame")
      .asFunction();
```

(the bools have to be converted to ints because the bool type is not supported yet (right?))

I'm trying to call this method from dart with a `Uint8List` coming from a frame of the camera stream https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/Plane-class.html but I'm not sure how to convert/allocate my `Uint8List` to `void *`

Any idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you're still having this issue but I recently found a way to pass camera data from the image stream api to c++.

**2020/01/08 Update**:

A working example can be found here https://github.com/martin-labanic/camera_preview_ffi_image_processing. Caveat: there is an issue here that is currently being investigated https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48360.

**Initial Answer**:

My setup:
    Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6)
        • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.6
        • Framework revision 18cd7a3601 (30 hours ago), 2019-12-11 06:35:39 -0800
        • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
        • Dart version 2.7.0
    ffi version 0.1.3 (https://pub.dev/packages/ffi)

In your flutter code prepare the image data with this:

```
import "dart:ffi" as ffi;

// 'data' is a Uint8List created by concatenating the planes received from the CameraImage the camera puts out.
// Based on the code found here https://github.com/renancaraujo/bitmap/blob/master/lib/ffi.dart in the execute function
// https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dart-ffi/list%7Csort:date/dart-ffi/V_6g5hpABec/U9we6UyvBAAJ
  final ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8> frameData = allocate<ffi.Uint8>(count: data.length); // Allocate a pointer large enough.
  final pointerList = frameData.asTypedList(data.length); // Create a list that uses our pointer and copy in the image data.
  pointerList.setAll(0, data);
```

This is using the `allocation.dart` file found in [the ffi example repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/tree/master/lib/src).

This is the binding I use in flutter:

```
final int Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8>, int, int, int) cppFunc = dynamicLibrary
    .lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Int32 Function(ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint8>, ffi.Int32, ffi.Int32, ffi.Int32)>>("cppFunc")
    .asFunction();
```

The c++ function looks like this:

```
extern "C" {
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used))
    int cppFunc(unsigned char *data, int width, int height, int scanline) {
.
.
.
```

I have no idea if this will continue to work as the dart:ffi progresses towards 1.0 but I'll try to keep this answer up to date.